# Arrange close votes in review by my tags

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

During [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) the highest number of pending reviews are always close votes. For example, right now there are 50k close votes, the others are less than 5. However, I think reviewing close votes is significantly different than reviewing others like a suggested edit. Many times it is difficult to say whether a question should really be closed if I don't have any idea on that topic.

So, is it possible to sort the close votes review tasks according to my tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can click on the `filter` link (next to the 'Review | Close Votes' heading) and filter on your 3 favorite tags and the type of close votes.

[image: filter option]
[image: tag filtering]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed that filter option.